# Mockbean containing autowired dependency

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-test

I'm testing a class which has a dependency to a bean. Within the test I mock the bean but the mocked bean also has it's own `@Autowired` dependency. Is there anyway for me to satisfy this dependency? As it is now, the `@Autowired` dependency is **null** when the method in the mock is called.

Example:

```
public class testclass {
    @Autowired
    private ClassToTest classToTest;
    @MockBean
    private DependencyOfClassToTest dependencyOfClassToTest;
    @Mockbean
    private MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock;
}

public class DependencyOfClassToTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock;
}
```

As seen above the mocked bean contains an `@Autowired` dependency.

Any solutions to this or am I breaking some sort of testing rule?

When the actual method in the mocked bean is called, it makes a call to **myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock** which will be null cause it's a mockbean.

MockBeans are not **null** in the `@Autowired` class though so they are found by Spring Boot.

Comment: Are you certain that your test is using the mocked version of the bean? If it is, the internals of the 'real' bean shouldn't be relevant, the fact that the real bean happens to have other dependencies is irrelevant, that's the whole point of the mock.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Yes, I'm not supplying the bean to the class I'm testing in any other way than that annotation.

Comment: I think you might need to show more code - are you able to edit your post to include the test (hopefully a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? Also, how do you know that `MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock` is null?

Comment: If you call method on the mocked object it will all times return the null value, possible you thought it happens because your `MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock` was not autowired, but looks like you did not know how to use mocks. You should predefine behavior of called method. In this case if you call the method it should return your predefined value, and it is does not matter what is inside mocked object (i mean `MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock` and another objects can be null). Otherwise something wrong with you test configuration and you call methods on the real object.

Answer (score 0):

Mock that bean too!

```
    public class testclass {
        @Autowired
        private ClassToTest classToTest;
        @MockBean
        private DependencyOfClassToTest dependencyOfClassToTest;
        @MockBean
        private MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock;
    }

    public class DependencyOfClassToTest {
        @Autowired
        private MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock;
    }
```

---

**update**: below test class works for me

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ClassToTest classToTest;
    @MockBean
    private DependencyOfClassToTest dependencyOfClassToTest;
    @MockBean
    private MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        System.out.println("test"+myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock);
    }



    @TestConfiguration  
    static class Context{

        @Component
         static class ClassToTest{

            @Autowired
            private DependencyOfClassToTest  dependencyOfClassToTest;
        }

        @Component
         static class DependencyOfClassToTest{
            @Autowired
            private MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock myOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock;


        }

        @Component
         static class MyOwnDependencyINeedHereInTheMock{

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. MockBeans are only not null in the @Autowired field.

Comment: in the example you've given, ClassToTest should be the class being tested, and it should have DependencyOfClassToTest autowired within it, which it doesan't.